# How do I create a launcher for the Xampp control panel?

Tags: launcher, xampp

I've just installed ubuntu 12.04 on my DEll v1450 laptop.

I downloaded and installed XAMPP 1.7.7

After that I created xampp control panel by using this command:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop
```

File content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Start/Stop XAMPP
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Exec=gksudo “python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py”
Icon[en_CA]=/usr/share/icons/Tango/scalable/devices/network-wired.svg
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Name[en_CA]=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment[en_CA]=Start/Stop XAMPP
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Tango/scalable/devices/network-wired.svg
```

The file has "execute" permission already.

I tried to launch the launcher in Dash home but nothing appeared after typing my password.

What did I wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to run this command:

```
gksudo python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
```

And I got this error:

```
Error importing pygtk2 and pygtk2-libglade
```

Install python-libglade solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
```

Hope it's useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

This desktop-file seems right (I have almost the same). Maybe, you forgot to replace typographic quotes (as in your snipped) to normal quotes.